# Couldn't find Category with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have tags showing in my category show view. When someone views the Mobile Phones Category they will see tags at the top such as iphone, apple, 16gb, black and ect. When someone clicks on 16gb, it should show everything item with 16gb tagged in it.

When someone clicks on a tag i get this error.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CategoriesController#show
Couldn't find Category with 'id'=

    def set_category
      @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    end
```

I can't figure out how to fix it?

Im using act_as_taggable gem.

Here is category controller

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_category,   only: [:show]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: [:destroy, :index, :edit]

  def index
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def show
    if params[:tag]
      @items = Item.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @items = Item.where(category_id: @category.id).order("created_at DESC")
    end
  end

  def new
    @category = Category.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.save
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @category }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.update(category_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @category }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @category.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to categories_url, notice: 'Category was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_category
      @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    end

    def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:name, :parent_id)
    end

    # Confirms an admin user.
    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.try(:admin?)
    end

end
```

Here is my category show view.

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<div class = "col-md-3">
    <h1>
      <strong><%= @category.name %></strong>
    </h1>
</div>

<div class = "col-md-9">
    <div id="tag_cloud">
      <% tag_cloud Item.tag_counts, %w[s m l] do |tag, css_class| %>
        <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name), class: css_class %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
</div>

<div class = "col-md-12">
    <div class="line-separator"></div>
</div>

<div class = "col-md-12">
    <div id="items" class="transitions-enabled">
        <% @items.each do |item| %>
            <div class="box panel panel-default">
              <div class="itemlisttitle"><%= item.title %></div>    
            <%= link_to image_tag(item.image.url (:medium)), item %>
              <div class ="panel-body">
              <div class = "itemlistprice">$<%= item.price %></div>
              <div class = "itemlistretailer"><%= image_tag item.user.avatar(:thumb) %> Retailer: <%= link_to item.user.username, item.user %></div>
            </div>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is routes. So you can see how the tags are routed.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


      resources :categories

      get 'password_resets/new'

      get 'password_resets/edit'

      get 'sessions/new'

      resources :users
      get 'user_items'  => 'users#show_user_items'
      root 'items#home'
      get 'signup'  => 'users#new'
      get 'show'  => 'users#show'
      get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
      post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
      delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
      resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
      resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

      resources :items
      get 'items_new' => 'items#new'

      get 'tags/:tags', to: 'categories#show', as: :tag
```

Schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150731101116) do

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "ancestry"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "categories", ["ancestry"], name: "index_categories_on_ancestry"

  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.decimal  "price"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.integer  "category_id"
  end

  add_index "items", ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_items_on_user_id_and_created_at"
  add_index "items", ["user_id"], name: "index_items_on_user_id"

  create_table "taggings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "tag_id"
    t.integer  "taggable_id"
    t.string   "taggable_type"
    t.integer  "tagger_id"
    t.string   "tagger_type"
    t.string   "context",       limit: 128
    t.datetime "created_at"
  end

  add_index "taggings", ["tag_id", "taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context", "tagger_id", "tagger_type"], name: "taggings_idx", unique: true
  add_index "taggings", ["taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context"], name: "index_taggings_on_taggable_id_and_taggable_type_and_context"

  create_table "tags", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "name"
    t.integer "taggings_count", default: 0
  end

  add_index "tags", ["name"], name: "index_tags_on_name", unique: true

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "remember_digest"
    t.boolean  "admin",               default: false
    t.string   "activation_digest"
    t.boolean  "activated",           default: false
    t.datetime "activated_at"
    t.string   "reset_digest"
    t.string   ">"
    t.datetime "reset_sent_at"
    t.string   "avatar_file_name"
    t.string   "avatar_content_type"
    t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
    t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
    t.text     "description"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You doesn't pass a category id to the `tags/:tags` path, fix your routes to:

```
get 'tags/:tags/:id', to: 'categories#show', as: :tag
```

And views:

```
<div class = "col-md-9">
    <div id="tag_cloud">
      <% tag_cloud Item.tag_counts, %w[s m l] do |tag, css_class| %>
        <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name, @category.id), class: css_class %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Update:

> When i click on a tag it the category show view loads with the url
>   localhost:3000/tags/16gb/1 which is good. But it still shows all the
>   items. Lets say i clicked on 16gb. It's still showing all mobile
>   mobies in the category, when it should only be showing its with 16gb
>   tagged. Any clues?

Fix your show action:

```
def show
   @items = Item.where(category_id: @category.id, title: params[:tags]).order("created_at DESC")
end
```

Comment: Thanks. When i click on a tag it the category show view loads with the url http://localhost:3000/tags/16gb/1 which is good. But it still shows all the items. Lets say i clicked on 16gb. It's still showing all mobile mobies in the category, when it should only be showing its with 16gb tagged. Any clues?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Really appreciate it. Again an error. I have added my schema to this question. Error is ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Categories#show SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: items.tag_name: SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."category_id" = ? AND "items"."tag_name" IS NULL  ORDER BY created_at DESC.

Comment: yep, i noticed about `tag_name`!!! Try this `Item.where(category_id: @category.id, name: params[:tags])`

Comment: Thanks again. Yeah kinda same error QLite3::SQLException: no such column: items.name: SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."category_id" = ? AND "items"."name" IS NULL

Comment: @joeyk16 sorry, change `name` to `title` =).

Comment: so its  Item.where(category_id: @category.id, title: params[:tags]) ?

Comment: yep, as you want your `where` items by `category_id` and item `title` if i right understand.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now the links seem to work. You click on the Mobile Phone category its  http://localhost:3000/categories/1 then you click on a tag http://localhost:3000/tags/16gb/1. Only problem is that none of the items show anymore haha. So when you click on the mobile phone category none of the mobiles are showing anymore, same with the tags

Comment: @joeyk16 this is all about your app buisness-logic, i can't know all, i can just point you to the right direction, try to work around your show action, add if\else statements.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway. Soz i been working on it for ages. Just wish i could get this part done. I will be better of with my knowledge doing a controller. I followed a tutorial and the way its routed the tags is all very new to me.

Comment: the main key of the any tutorials is provides some example, don't follow it all, try to understand, use documentation, find examples in web. Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your `params[:id]` is empty. Either you should place your `tags` route under `categories` resource:

```
resources :categories
  member do
     # run 'rake routes' to check
     # the URL would be something like 'categiries/1/tags/16gb'
     get 'tags/:tag'
  end
end
```

or you should change `params[:id]` to `params[:category_id]` in your controller and use that parameter when creating URLs:

```
# in your index.html.erb or somewhere where you generate URLs which lead to 'show' action
tag_path(tag.name, category_id: tag.category.id)
```